# How to run plife.jl in julia/examples?

Tags: julia

I've installed Julia Version 0.3.10-pre+4 and am trying to run the examples contained in julia/examples, in particular `plife.jl`, which seems to be a parallel simulation of Conway's game of life.  I have the error

```
julia> include("plife.jl")
plife (generic function with 1 method)

julia> plife(100,100)
ERROR: Window not defined
 in plife at /x/faia/julia/examples/plife.jl:44
```

where the error is caused by the code

```
function plife(m, n)
    w = Window("parallel life", n, m)
    c = Canvas(w)
```

I have searched for a package that defines the Window function, but have failed to find it.  Does anyone know how to run this example code?

Answer (score 2):

That example seems to be reliant on an external package, it looks like it might be Tk.jl but there have been some renames since then.

It has actually been removed on the development branch of Julia, but still lingers in the 0.3 series. [I've filed a PR to remove it](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/12001).